# cached_property and classmethod doesnt work together, Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use `cached_property` and `classmethod` decorators together in a viewset but it doesnt work regardless of their mutual position. Is it any chance to make it work together or `cached_property` doesnt work with `classmethod`?
Tnanks.

```
    @cached_property
    @classmethod
    def get_child_extra_actions(cls):
        """
        Returns only extra actions defined in this exact viewset exclude actions defined in superclasses.
        """
        all_extra_actions = cls.get_extra_actions()
        parent_extra_actions = cls.__base__.get_extra_actions()
        child_extra_actions = set(all_extra_actions).difference(parent_extra_actions)
        return (act.__name__ for act in child_extra_actions)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For cached property with classmethod usage i wrote that code a few days ago:

```
from django.utils.decorators import classproperty

class cached_classproperty(classproperty):
    def get_result_field_name(self):
        return self.fget.__name__ + "_property_result" if self.fget else None

    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        result_field_name = self.get_result_field_name()

        if hasattr(cls, result_field_name):
            return getattr(cls, result_field_name)

        if not cls or not result_field_name:
            return self.fget(cls)

        setattr(cls, result_field_name, self.fget(cls))
        return getattr(cls, result_field_name)
```

It will be caching result in class-level.
Usage is similar as `classproperty`:

```
@cached_classproperty
def some_func(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

If you do not have django in dependencies, then you may want prevent `classproperty` parent usage ([sources](https://docs.djangoproject.com/id/3.0/_modules/django/utils/decorators/)). In that case you may use that decorator:

```
class cached_classproperty(classproperty):
    def __init__(self, method=None):
        self.fget = method

    def get_result_field_name(self):
        return self.fget.__name__ + "_property_result" if self.fget else None

    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        result_field_name = self.get_result_field_name()

        if hasattr(cls, result_field_name):
            return getattr(cls, result_field_name)

        if not cls or not result_field_name:
            return self.fget(cls)

        setattr(cls, result_field_name, self.fget(cls))
        return getattr(cls, result_field_name)

    def getter(self, method):
        self.fget = method
        return self
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's classproperty? Is it some extra package???

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich  sorry, forgot the import. One min.

Comment: @ncopiy thanks for the code, how do you expire the cache?

Comment: @eugene there is a class-based cache, it means you will have a new field in your class with function result (`self.fget.__name__ + "_property_result"`). it will be invalidate only in situation, when new you implement new class, for ex in new python process. or you can add time handling in this code by yourself if you want to use time-based cache